# C# using OAuthAuthorizationServer custom endpoint and token expiry

Tags: c#, .net, oauth, token, access-token

I have an OAuth implementation guided by this blog post [Token based auth in asp.net](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/) and everything is working really nicely. In all the examples I can find on the net, we provide an endpoint (ie '/accesstoken') and the framework takes care of routing/controllers etc for us.

However, this allows little customisation. The endpoint currently returns this:

```
{
  "access_token": "...",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "expires_in": 31535999
}
```

I want to be able to add additional attributes to this document, ideally from an existing controller, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using custom `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider. Then you can override the behaviour that adds elements to the result there. I think if you create a default solution with this type of authentication in Visual Studio 2013, then you have a very good example on how to achieve this.